# How to compare two dates of format dd MMM yyyy hh.mm AM/PM?

Tags: android

I want the result which date is greater means want to compare two dates in android of format(dd MMM yyyy hh.mm AM/PM) 
e.g a) 27 Nov 2017 06.00 AM 
b) 27 Nov 2017 06.10 AM
I want to compare a and b dates and want result that b date is greater than a date.

Please anyone know how to compare

Comment: Without converting in milliseconds I want the output..

Comment: 1/ parse 2/ compare

Answer (score 2):

You can simply campare two dates.

```
 SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh.mm a");
            Date date1 = sdf.parse(yourdateA);
            Date date2 = sdf1.parse(yourdateB);
            if (date1.after(date2)) {
               // Validate here
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way . just make date format as you required

```
public static boolean CheckDates(String startDate, String endDate) {

    SimpleDateFormat dfDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy hh.mm a");

    boolean b = false;

    try {
        if (dfDate.parse(startDate).before(dfDate.parse(endDate))) {
            b = true;  // If start date is before end date.
        } else if (dfDate.parse(startDate).equals(dfDate.parse(endDate))) {
            b = true;  // If two dates are equal.
        } else {
            b = false; // If start date is after the end date.
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return b;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code for comparing dates in Android:

```
  if(a.isBefore( b ))
     //code results for a is lesser than b
  else
    //code results for a is greater than b
```